# Why is <reference path="..." /> required when Importing dojox/gfx with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dojox.gfx

We have a TypeScript project where we need to uses Dojo's `createSurface`. However, we unexpectedly need to include `<reference path="..."/>` as shown below.

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/dojo/dojox.gfx.d.ts"/>
import gfx1 = require("dojox/gfx");
import gfx2 from "dojox/gfx";
import * as gfx3 from "dojox/gfx";
import { createSurface } from "dojox/gfx";

const el = new HTMLElement();

gfx1.createSurface(el, 100, 100); // require
gfx2.createSurface(el, 100, 100); // from
gfx3.createSurface(el, 100, 100); // star
createSurface(el, 100, 100);      // single method
```

I would have expected to not require `<reference path="..."/>` but without it TypeScript complains that it cannot find the module for each require/import statement shown.

Our package.json is

```
{
  "name": "react-dojo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dojo": "1.9.40",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "dojo": "^1.13.0",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Our tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

How do (can) we import Dojox modules without `<reference path=""/>`?

#### Update 04 JUN 2018

Upon further inspection of dojo's type definitions I found that I can dojox without the `<reference path="..."/>` like so...

```
import * as dojox from "dojo/main.dojox";
dojox.gfx.createSurface(el, 100, 100);

// or

import { gfx } from "dojo/main.dojox";
gfx.createSurface(el, 100, 100);
```

This is because `@types/dojo/index.d.ts` exports the following module.

```
declare module "dojo/main.dojox" {
    var exp: dojo.main.dojox
    export=exp;
}
```

However, the dojox interface in `index.d.ts` defines gfx as an `Object`. Typescript then warns that

> Property 'createSurface' does not exist on type 'dojox'

As a test I created a new project with only the following dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/dojo": "1.9.40",
  "typescript": "2.9.1"
}
```

I then changed `gfx: Object` to `gfx: dojox.gfx;` within `index.d.ts`. This seemed to resolve all issues for this test project.

I attempted to do the same to my original project but TypeScript warns that

> node_modules/@types/dojo/index.d.ts(26014,24): error TS2694: Namespace 'dojox' has no exported member 'gfx'.

I have verified that the contents of `node_modules/@types/dojo` are identical, and both projects use the same TypeScript version. The tsconfig.json files are the same as well.

Why would one project see the exported member and another not?